# Exporting Image with all tooltip in high charts angular

Tags: angular, highcharts, tooltip, angular2-highcharts

How can I export the chart with all tooltip displaying in high charts as a image, pdf & jpeg.

here is the code for tooltip:-

```
tooltip: {
    hideDelay: 0,
    headerFormat: '',
    enabled: true,
    split: true,
    animation: false,
    valueDecimals: 2,
    outside: true,
    shared: false,
},
```

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this approach:

```
 exporting: {
    chartOptions: { // specific options for the exported image
      chart: {
        events: {
          load: function() {
            const chart = this;

            chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.series[0].data[0]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/50vz7edt/

Comment: thanks for the answer. but, i want to display all tooltips while downloading not working in my case with the same code. how can i do that? please suggest

Comment: Is there any way to display all tooltips while exporting as png

Comment: @ParthRaval That's impossible - tooltip is rendered dynamically for each point after hovering it. I think that for your needs you will need to create a custom tooltip for each point.

Comment: Okay, can you please help me to display custom tooltip?

Comment: IS there any example available?

Comment: take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qx5ojskz/ you can mix this code with the config from the answer to show custom tooltips only for exported images.